# can we read and program the microcodes of AMD processor?

Tags: encryption, amd-processor

we can know that microcodes in Intel processors is encrypted (as issued in "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual"). One cannot programm the Intel microcodes as he wants.

So, does anyone know how about the AMD microcodes? Are the microcodes of AMD CPU encrypted ?

Anyone knows how to program microcodes? It's doesn't limit on AMD or Intel CPUs.

Thank you in advance!

(ps: Not the microcodes in GPU, but in CPU).

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The microcode in the processor controls fantastically parallel clock-based signal propagation at, like, the transistor level.  Who would write anything at such a spectacularly low level unless, you know, you're designing a CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5FP0M1PDFO.html) provides information on the microcode of AMD's Opteron (K8) family. It claims that it is not encrypted and provides information on the microcode format and updating the microcode.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But is it encrypted in the latter family? like K10, K11 or newer families?

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone knows how to program microcodes? It's doesn't limit on AMD or Intel CPUs.

Not too many people do that kind of work. It's often written with a C compiler tweaked to generate the necessary microcode.

To answer your question in regard "is there other processors accepting microcode?" FPGA's are only programmed using such. These are not CPUs, what you program in them "is written at the hardware level". The microcode changes the doors and the result is your program. It can become very tedious as everything runs in parallel (true hardware parallelism).

Comment: Thank you. I mean that if we can programming in the processors, especially using the microcodes, which may be attacked by hardware hackers for their possibility to be modified under certain privilege. So , I want to get some more information about this.

Comment: Then I guess the encrypted INTEL microcode scheme is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

AMD microcode for recent processors is, indeed, encrypted and authenticated,  much like Intel's.  You need to have the proper crypto key to sign a microcode update the processor will accept.

Intel does it by embedding in the processor mask (hardware read-only) microcode a hash of the valid key(s?): the key itself is too large to bother embedding in the processor, so it will be present in the update data itself as seen [here](http://www.inertiawar.com/microcode/).  Also, the Intel microcode update is actually an unified processor-package update data, it updates more than just the microcode for the decode unit.  It can update all sort of internal processor parameters, as well as control sequences for other units than the decoder...  it also has both opcode (and likely microcode) that the processor runs before(?)/after applying the update.